# C++ serialization: overloading insert operator with write()

Tags: c++, serialization, operator-overloading, class-design, iostream

I have a simple class which contains a dynamically allocated array and I need to serialize it so it can be stored in a binary file. Because of the array I can't use sizeof(MyClass) to simply allocate a buffer.

The class looks like this:

```
class ReplayFrame
{
public:
    // ...

private:
    int dataType_;
    int timeStamp_;
    int frameNumber_;
    size_t dataSize_;
    char* data_;
};
```

And here's a solution that I've come up with:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const ReplayFrame& frame)
{
    out.write((char *) &frame.dataType_, sizeof(int));
    out.write((char *) &frame.timeStamp_, sizeof(int));
    out.write((char *) &frame.frameNumber_, sizeof(int));
    out.write((char *) &frame.dataSize_, sizeof(size_t));
    out.write(frame.data_, frame.dataSize_);

    return out;
}
```

This seems fine to me, but it somewhat changes the meaning of the << operator. So maybe something like `std::ostream& ReplayFrame::serialize(std::ostream& out, const ReplayFrame& frame)` would be better instead?

Or maybe I should have a `serialize()` method which doesn't use stream but instead returns size and a pointer to serialized object which I then write myself, like:

```
ReplayFrame replayFrame;
int size;

char *frameSerialized = replayFrame.serialize(size);
fileStream.write(frameSerialized, size);

delete frameSerialized; // or frameSerialized.release() ?
```

As you can see I'm quite confused so I'm open to any good suggestions. (Note: I use Qt, no boost and no c++11).

Comment: I think, `<<` + `ostream` are reserved for text representation. For serialization, I would perhaps just use `serialize` method.

Comment: and you perhaps shouldn't rely on `sizeof`, as some day your class might change to contain dynamically allocated memory (e.g., `std::string`)

Answer (score 1):

Important things first: Just dumping binary data anywhere, whether it is a file, another process, or whatever is a Bad Idea. You **always** want to *format* the data, although the format can be binary and it may match aspects of the internal representation of the system you are currently developing on. However, you should realize that any marginally successful program will outlive different compiler generations, possibly processor upgrades, and get ported to another platform. If you binary format depends on how the compiler happens to represent data right now all of these will be headache. If the program ends up successful, it will be an even bigger headache.

The aspects of a binary format you want to pay attention to are

- size of individual words
- ordering of bytes within words
- potential padding between words
- order of data items written

Just using, for example, `sizeof()` to determine how many bytes are dumped or read doesn't work between 32 bit and 64 bit platforms. Just dumping out bytes in the order they come doesn't work, e.g., between PowerPC and x86 systems. Just dumping out bytes may be easy now but in the mid-term it will create more problems.

Overloading the output operators is OK, as long as you **don't** use the text formatted stream classes with this operators! You can use the `std::streambuf` layer which is concerned with reading and writing bytes, e.g., `std::filebuf` to read from or write to a file, but for binary formatted stream you want to a dedicated system of binary streams when overloading `operator<<()`. Of course, this means that classes would need to overload the corresponding operations to work in this serialization system but mixing text and binary formatted idea is almost certain to cause a lot of grief.